# Сортировка чисел в массиве используя Math.random

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

Объясните пожалуйста как и каким образом работает данная сортировка. Так как встретив эту задачу хотелось бы больше осмыслить процесс происходящий за данной сортировкой.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function compareRandom(a, b) {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;    
}

arr.sort(compareRandom);

alert(arr); // элементы в случайном порядке, например [3,5,1,2,4]
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Кстати, результат сортировки для недетерминированных функций полностью зависит от [реализации движка JS](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). Так что в общем случае я бы не был на 100% уверен, что порядок элементов будет случайным.

Answer (score 5):

Вот, для начала, как работает метод `Array.prototype.sort([compareFunction])`. Он принимает в качестве аргумента необязательный параметр `[compareFunction]`, который представляет из себя функцию, определяющую порядок сортировки.

Например:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a "меньше" b согласно какому-то критерию) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a "больше" b согласно какому-то критерию) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a == b
  return 0;
}
```

Тогда, если `compare(a, b)` меньше 0, сортировка поставит **a** по меньшему индексу, чем **b**, то есть, **a** идёт первым. И наоборот, если `compare(a, b)` больше 0, сортировка поставит **b** по меньшему индексу, чем **a**.

Таким образом, принимая во внимание, что `Math.random()` возвращает псевдослучайное число с плавающей точкой в интервале **[0; 1)**, мы получаем диапазон возвращаемых значений функции `function compareRandom(a, b)` в интервале **[-0,5; 0,5)**. Исходя из этого, у нас шансы (примерно) 50%/50% получения негативного *(a < b)* значения функции, и такие-же шансы получения позитивного *(a > b)* значения. И так для каждого элемента, что участвует в сравнении. Соответственно, в вашей ситуации, `arr.sort(compareRandom);` после каждого вызова отсортирует массив по-разному.

Вывод: после выполнения `arr.sort(compareRandom);` вы получите один из **n!** вариантов размещения элементов в массиве, где n - количество элементов массива.

Детальнее про сортировку [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: и всё же почему оно работает? Вот пример на С++ http://ideone.com/EpDw90 тут видно что оно не работает. Насколько я помню операция сравнения должна быть транзитивной и так далее.

Comment: Интервал `[-0,5; 0,49)` неверен. Должно быть `[-0,5; 0,5)`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, учитывая, что диапазон возвращаемых значений Math.random() находится в интервале от нуля (включая) до единицы (НЕ включая), получаем, что диапазон значений (Math.random() - 0.5) будет равен: от 0 - 0.5= -0.5 (включая) до 0.9(9) - 0.5 = 0.49(9).

Comment: @pavel, я не експерт в С++, но разве `return rand()&1;` возвращает не **0** для любого значения `rand()` отличного от **1**? Попробуйте заменить `return rand()&1;` на `return (rand() > (RAND_MAX / 2))` и все должно заработать. Суть ведь в том, чтобы "компаратор" равновозможно и, в тоже время, случайно сообщал **а** больше **b**, или же нет. Только таким образом мы случайно получим один из **n!** возможных вариантов размещения n-го количества элементов в массиве.

Comment: @Nk185 нет, то побитовое И эквиватентно return (rand()%2 == 1). Просто тут проблема что если a > b и b > a то например С++ начинает КРАЙНЕ неадекватно себя вести (вплоть на ошибки времени выполнения). Даже в этом примере видно что взяты значения за границей массива. Вот и интересуюсь как так получается что в JS этот код корректно работает, там что специальный алгоритм сортировки?

Comment: @Nk185, именно об этом и говорит запись `[-0,5; 0,5)`. Правая граница **не включена** в диапазон. Записывая диапазон как `[-0,5; 0,49)` вы теряете один процент значений (если распределение равномерное). Согласитесь -- это не очень-то здорово

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ой, точно, прошу прощения, не заметил. Вы правы.